# extracting specific data from a table

Tags: python, perl, bash, shell

I have table which looks like this (tab separated):

```
Ron  Rob  rock bammy
m    f   m  f
florida  Atlanta  florida texas
```

This table is of order 5*512 and based on row 3 data, I want to extract the values in row1.
 for example: I want to have names of all person living in florida and texas, in a table of 2 columns and n number of rows.

```
Florida  Ron
Florida  Rock
Texas BAmmy
```

and so on.

any suggestions for a bash or PERL liners...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post a bigger sample of your input file.

Comment: 5 row and 512 columns, I want to extract the data in first row based on the value of the data in row 3.

Comment: Are there really spaces on either side of the tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)n[i]=$i}; NR==3{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/florida|texas/)print $i"\t"n[i];}}' yourFile
```

see the test below:

```
kent$  echo "Ron Rob rock bammy
m f m f
florida Atlanta florida texas"|awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)n[i]=$i}; NR==3{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/florida|texas/)print $i"\t"n[i];}}'
```

**output**

```
florida Ron
florida rock
texas   bammy
```

**EDIT**

```
kent$  echo "Ron  Rob  rock bammy
m    f   m  f
florida(8)  Atlanta  florida(8) texas(2;7)"|awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)n[i]=$i}; NR==3{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/florida\(8\)|texas\(2;7\)/)print $i"\t"n[i];}}'
```

output:

```
florida(8)      Ron
florida(8)      rock
texas(2;7)      bammy
```

Comment: what if, I have to match something like florida(8) and texas(2;7). How  can I put this .... single quote or double .... nothing working

Answer (score 1):

Yet another Perl solution:

```
perl -ane 'push@c,@F}{print grep{/^(florida|atlanta)\t/i}map{"$c[$_+$#c/3*2+1]\t$c[$_]\n"}0..$#c/3'
```

Or as a script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my (@data, @rows);

push @data, split/\s+/ while (<>);

for (0 .. $#data/3) {
    my $name = $data[$_];
    my $location = $data[$_+$#data/3*2+1];
    push @rows, "$location\t$name\n" if $location =~ /^(florida|atlanta)$/i;
}

print join("", @rows);
```

with an if condition inside the loop instead of the separate `grep`.

My approach is to flatten all three lines into a single array and use `for (0 .. $#data/3)` to loop over the indexes corresponding to the names from the first line and get the location from the matching column with `$data[$_+$#data/3*2+1]`.

Comment: A very nice solution, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl solution that works, but it's a bit more convoluted that I'd like. You'd probably be better off putting this data into a database.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %rows = (
  name => 1,
  location => 3,
);

my %location = map { $_ => 1 } qw[florida texas];

my @names;

while (<DATA>) {
  next unless grep { $_ == $. } values %rows;

  chomp;

  if ($. == $rows{name}) {
    @names = split;
  }

  if ($. == $rows{location}) {
    my @locs = split;

    for my $x (0 .. $#locs) {
      if ($location{lc $locs[$x]}) {
        say ucfirst $locs[$x]. "\t$names[$x]";
      }
    }
    last;
  }
}

__END__
Ron     Rob     rock    bammy
m       f       m       f
florida         Atlanta florida texas
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pat = shift;

sub interleave($$){
    my ($foo,$bar) = @_;
    return map { ( $_ , shift @{$bar} ) } @{$foo};
}

my $n=0;
my(@p,%h);
while(<>){
    chomp;
    if($n%3==0){
            @p = split /\t/, $_;
    } elsif($n%3==2){
            my @l = split /\t/, $_;
            my %kv = interleave(\@p, \@l);
            foreach my $k (keys %kv){
                    push(@{$h{$kv{$k}}}, $k);
            }
    }
    $n++;
}

foreach my $loc (keys %h){
    if(!defined $pat || $loc =~ /$pat/i){
            foreach my $name (@{$h{$loc}}){
                    print ucfirst($loc), "\t", ucfirst($name), "\n";
            }
    }
}
```

And then call it

```
perl extract.pl 'texas|florida' < data
```

"Oneliner" form:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$p=shift||"^";}chomp;if($n++%3!=1){unless(@p){@p=split/\t/,$_;next;}my %kv = map { ( $_ , shift @p ) } split(/\t/, $_);map { push(@{$h{$_}}, $kv{$_}); } keys %kv;}END{map{for my$nm(@{$h{$_}}){print ucfirst($_),"\t",ucfirst($nm),"\n";}}grep{/$p/i}keys%h;}' 'florida|texas' < data
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like this is a job for [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS). It is **not** a good idea to split on whitespace, as many seem to be suggesting, as that will fail for anything but simplified data.

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( {
        sep_char    => "\t",
        binary      => 1,
    });

# get array refs to each row, with appropriate name
# For larger data sets, using an array to hold the array refs would be better
my $name       = $csv->getline(*DATA);
my $gender     = $csv->getline(*DATA);
my $city       = $csv->getline(*DATA);

for (keys @$city) {   # lists the column numbers
    if ($city->[$_] =~ /florida|texas/i) {
        print "$city->[$_]\t$name->[$_]\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
Ron Rob rock    bammy
m   f   m   f
florida Atlanta florida texas
```

**Output:**

```
florida Ron
florida rock
texas   bammy
```